# slug is not working properly in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating pages with slug in codeigniter. But it is not working if my slug in database have slashes.

like -:

1) con_r/this  //not working

2) con_q //working

3) con_r/this/that //not working

Take a look at my code

**routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = 'home';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;

require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB'. EXT );
$db =& DB();
$query = $db->get('slugu');
$result = $query->result();
foreach( $result as $row ){
    $route[ $row->slug ] = 'page/call/'.$row->slug;
}
```

**Page** //controller

```
 public function call($slug){

    $data['page_base'] = $this->site_model->get_page_info($slug);

    /*call slider*/
    echo $this->call_slider($slug);

    if (empty($data['page_base'])){
        show_404();
    }

    print_R($data['page_base']);
    die;
}
```

Comment: try to print_r($route) in routes.php to see how routes are coming.

Comment: Try encoding the forward slashes in your slugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the way CodeIgniter handles URL's. The first two URL segments is the class and function. The third and any more segments are passed into the function as variables. So in your example the following URL works because the full slug is passed into the function:

```
example.com/page/call/con_q

public function call($slug) {
  echo $slug; // con_q
}
```

Whereas the following does not because only the first segment of the slug is passed into the function

```
example.com/page/call/con_r/this

public function call($slug) {
  echo $slug; // con_r NOT con_r/this
}

public function call($segment_1, $segment_2) {
  echo $segment_1; // con_r
  echo $segment_2; // this
}
```

A solution which I think would work would be the following. Please note that this is untested and may need some modifications.

```
example.com/page/call/con_r/this

public function call() {
  $slug = func_get_args();
  $slug = implode('/', $slug);
  echo $slug; // con_r/this
}
```

Comment: you was right your solution may not work in ALL* condition but it is working in my condition